# what is this error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react2.PropType.number')?

Tags: react-native

While running react-native program on android emulator, I am facing this error. What is react2 here? I have tried many things like adding dependencies in android project folder and this is some code snippet of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.50.2",
    "react-native-button": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.22"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Add prop-types library dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
     "prop-types": "^15.5.7" 
 }
```

or just install it with npm

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Comment: not working.. tried both options, and thanks for answer +1

Comment: @fazeelreact After version 15.5 you have to import PropTypes, so check if you have "import PropTypes from 'prop-types';" in the file in which you use prop-types